# Pthread: How exactly work rwlockattr

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads, rwlock

I've got a question about "rwlocks", especial about "rwlockattr".

I've got a linked list with several threads working with. Every Member on this list has got a "rwlock". So now I want to set up a rule to secure that threads who want access a write-lock have a higher priority. My intention is to use

int pthread_rwlockattr_setkind_np(pthread_rwlockattr_t *attr,int pref);

So now my Question; Do I need to initialize a "rwlockattr" for every "rwlock" in my linked List or is it enough to set up a global "rwlockattr", initialize it and set up the "PTHREAD_RWLOCK_PREFER_WRITER_NP" rule ?

regards

Comment: Simply creating a global rwlockattr object has no effect on anything. The rest of the system has no way to use that global or even know it exists. You need to use the attributes when initializing each rwlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every rwlock there is some by default attributes associated with it. For the `pthread_rwlock_init()` go through this [link](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_rwlock_init) which will give you more information that how to use rwlock.

You can assign single attribute to your rwlocks. You globally create a single attribute and assign to your rwlocks having the same nature.

Go through [this](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/users_86.htm) to understand the use of **pthread_rwlock**.

```
In general Attributes are to decide the nature of your rwlock.
```

Comment: Ah ok nice thx , btw is there any possibility to get this function in the win32 version of pthread ? I tried to transfer my code from unix to win32 but in the win32 version of Pthread seems to be no support for this, is this correct?

Comment: No win32 does not support pthread library natively. For win32 pthreading support go through [this](https://www.sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) link.